# Gnome taskbar on multiple monitors

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, taskbar

**Using Ubuntu 12.10 with GNOME 3.6**

I have plugged in a second monitor to my laptop and can drag windows between. I am using Compiz to handle virtual desktops and have switched that to scroll desktops at the same time.

How can I show the taskbar on both monitors, and only the windows on that monitor show on that taskbar?

For **bonus points** can I set it so that when I plug in my number of desktops decreases - I no longer need to have 2x horizontally, just vertically. If I unplug I'd like the second screen to switch to desktops 2 and 4 respectively.

Answer (score 13):

- A lot of guides say to `right click` on the taskbar or other panel. I found that I had to hold down `Alt`+`Super` and right click. I also had to do it on a blank area, not a current taskbar button.
- Click `New panel`
- Find where the new panel has been added - with a default config it will likely be to the right of the screen.
- Hold the same key combination as above and `drag` the panel to the second screen. Snap it to whichever edge you want.
- Use the combination again, right click the new panel and click `Add to panel`
- In the list scroll to the bottom to find `Window list`
- This should be added and pull in any windows on the current screen.

If you need to reset the Gnome panels at any point the command line `killall gnome-panel` should cause them to be removed and restart themselves.

Still bonus points for the rest of the question above!

Comment: That does not work for me. Pushing Alt + Super + Rightclick just showing the usual Menu where I can choose Display Settings and Settings.